# Supervisor communication in storm 0.9.0.1 with Netty

Tags: java, tcp, netty, apache-storm

I've setted up a cluster 0.9.0.1 version.

dedicated nimbus, zookeeper, two supervisors.

Have to say that everything works just fine with one supervisor. But when I add another one, task from one machine can't communicate with task on another machine, and because of that, messages are getting timed out.

I'm running everything on AWS using CentOS instances. I'v opend all ports for supervisor security group. Stoped iptables. But still no luck.

when I do `netstat -a` I can see `ESTABLISHED` connections between servers. I can also successfully `ping` each other.

No need to say that zookeeper works fine, and I can run `echo ruok | nc <ip> 2181` and I'm getting result.

But when Im checking worker log, I see those errors:

```
2014-03-13 13:53:28 STDIO [ERROR] Mar 13, 2014 1:53:28 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline
WARNING: An exception was thrown by a user handler while handling an exception event ([id: 0x4bb68a13] EXCEPTION: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.reconnect(Client.java:94)
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.StormClientHandler.exceptionCaught(StormClientHandler.java:118)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:109)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:78)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-03-13 13:53:29 b.s.m.n.StormClientHandler [INFO] Connection failed:
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:148) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:104) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:78) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:41) ~[netty-3.6.3.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: what are the contents of your storm.yaml file? Can you ping the IPs in it from all the hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Check that every node has /etc/hosts file written with all the references (hostname and IP) to the hosts belonging to the cluster.